# Undefined variable in FPDF. help me. mysqli

Tags: pdf, fpdf

why Notice: Undefined variable: datanya?
can you fixed? this is my code:
how do i fix it.

```
require("fpdf.php");
$konek=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","rollab");
$kode=$_GET['kode'];
$query=mysqli_query($konek,"select*from wp_jadwal where id_jadwal='.$kode.'");
$datanya =mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

class myPDF extends FPDF{
    function headerPro(){
       $this->Ln(13);
        $this->Cell(40,5,$datanya["tanggalpemutaran"],0,0,'L');
        $this->Ln();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [this](http://fpdf.org/en/FAQ.php#q5) FAQ of FPDF. It's for the default Header/Footer methods but it's the same issue:

**5. I try to display a variable in the Header method but nothing prints.**

You have to use the global keyword to access global variables, for example:

```
function Header()
{
    global $title;

    $this->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 15);
    $this->Cell(0, 10, $title, 1, 1, 'C');
}

$title = 'My title';
```

Alternatively, you can use an object property:

```
function Header()
{
    $this->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 15);
    $this->Cell(0, 10, $this->title, 1, 1, 'C');
}

$pdf->title = 'My title';
```

Comment: thank you, but how do i connect it with mysqli? when I put the $datanya code in viewTable (), it was also an error